# Ruby csv import get code smaller but equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I'm new to rails and ruby...
How can i refactor such code, which import's from csv file data?
Now i have such code

```
  if row[qnt].to_s != ""
    eqnt = /(\d+)/.match(row[qnt])[0].to_s
  else
    eqnt = 0
  end
```

I try something like

```
if row[qnt].present?
        eqnt = /(\d+)/.match(row[qnt])[0].to_s
      else
        eqnt = 0
      end
```

But is it equal, and also what else could i do to get code smaller?

Comment: `present?` documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F Some examples of present?: `[].present? #=> false` | `nil.present? #=> false` | `"".present? #=> false` | `" ".present? #=> false` (empty string)

Comment: But OP is already using `present?`, I think the point is that the OP wants to have so-called "elegant" code.

Comment: No. Valdis said "I try something like [code] But is it equal, and also [blabla]". I assume Valdis is asking about `present?` and `.to_s != ""`.

Comment: He's asking if `present?` can be equated to `.to_s != ""` and also make the code cleaner and/smaller. That's what I get from this.

Comment: @LeoCorrea you are right

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
row[qnt].present? ? eqnt = /(\d+)/.match(row[qnt])[0].to_s : eqnt = 0
```

Comment: Ugh, two assignment statements where one would do, and IMO be easier to understand.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with you, I wrote it without thinking much of the assignment and more about compressing code. To be honest, my first thought was to go with your second option as it's the most readable one but I figured since the OP wanted to make the code smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the code gains readability by trying to compress it much further.

```
eqnt = row[qnt].present? ? /(\d+)/.match(row[qnt])[0].to_s : 0
```

Or

```
eqnt = 0
eqnt = /(\d+)/.match(row[qnt])[0].to_s if row[qnt].present?
```

Or

```
theRow = row[qnt]
eqnt = theRow.present? ? /(\d+)/.match(theRow).first.to_s : 0
```

Or better yet, extract this into a method, keep the mainline code clean, and isolate the logic.

I'm not psyched about `eqnt` ending up with different types, though, unless that's by design.

Answer (score 0):

```
eqnt = (/(\d+)/.match(row[qnt]) || [0])[0]
```